# Generating function from recurrence relation of binomial distribution

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions, recursive-algorithms

Hello i have given recurrence like this :

$$p_{n,k}=(1-q)p_{n-1,k-1}+qp_{n-1,k}$$

my question is how to get (step by step) generating function from this recurrence?

we know that it's some king of distribution and from how it looks we can say it's binomial distribution.

Comment: Which kind of generating function do you want? Probability, moment, cumulant?

Comment: i think Probability would be the best one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability generating function is $G_n(t):=\sum_{k=0}^n p_{n,\,k}t^k$, so $G_0=1$ and for $n\ge 1$ we have $$G_n(t)=q^n+\sum_{k=1}^n ((1-q)p_{n-1,\,k-1}+qp_{n-1,\,k})t^k\\=q^n+(1-q)tG_{n-1}(t)+q(G_{n-1}(t)-q^{n-1})\\=(q+(1-q)t)G_{n-1}(t).$$Hence $G_n(t)=(q+(1-q)t)^n$ for all $n$.